# How to access file in parent directory using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-os

I am trying to access a text file in the parent directory,

Eg : python script is in **codeSrc** & the text file is in **mainFolder**.

#### script path:

```
G:\mainFolder\codeSrc\fun.py
```

#### desired file path:

```
G:\mainFolder\foo.txt
```

I am currently using this syntax with python 2.7x,

```
import os 
filename = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())+"\\foo.txt"
```

Although this works fine, is there a better (prettier :P) way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While your example works, it is maybe not the nicest, neither is mine, probably. Anyhow, `os.path.dirname()` is probably meant for strings where the final part is already a filename. It uses `os.path.split()`, which provides an empty string if the path end with a slash. So this potentially can go wrong. Moreover, as you are already using `os.path`, I'd also use it to join paths, which then becomes even platform independent. I'd write

```
os.path.join( os.getcwd(), '..', 'foo.txt' )
```

...and concerning the readability of the code, here (as in the post using the environ module) it becomes evident immediately that you go one level up.

Comment: I think i will go with the os.path.join method , as environ is not part of the python 2.7.13 package. 
.
Have you tested the os.path.join method in a linux environment ?

Comment: While I am working on Linux I tested this on Win7 as your use of `G:\ ` suggested.

Comment: Good guess :) ,  If I choose to port to a linux environment in the future do you see any drawbacks for the os.path.join method.

Comment: @EdmundCarvalho No, the contrary; that's exactly why you'd use `os`. This code runs just as fine in Linux, no changes required.

Answer (score 1):

To get a path to a file in the parent directory of the current script you can do:

```
import os
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'foo.txt')
```

Comment: This is the one I needed because the file I am assembling the path from is nested lower than the active working directory. I can't make the assumption that execution is occurring in the same dir as the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
import environ
environ.Path() - 1 + 'foo.txt'
```

Comment: is `environ.Path()` equivalent to `environ.Path( __file__ )` ?

Comment: No, not exactly.
environ.Path() will give you path till current directory. This is give you output similar to pwd command in linux

Comment: **package doesn't work with py 3.8**                                 
    import environ
  File "C:\Users...\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\environ.py", line 114
    raise ValueError, "No frame marked with %s." % fname
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

to get the parent dir the below code will help you:

```
import os
os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', os.getcwd()))
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this using Python >=3.4 I found the following method the easiest

```
from pathlib import Path
filename = Path("../foo.txt").resolve()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve